# Centering a heading <h1>

Tags: html, css

Quick question, I have a DIV with a H1 inside it, now , I wish to Center my H1 inside this DIV...

I try the following which does not work:

set the H1:

```
display:inline
margin-left: auto ; 
margin-right: auto ;
```

But I try this and it does work, can someone explain why the above DOESN'T work?

set the H1:

```
width: 35%;
margin-left: auto ; 
margin-right: auto ;
```

Comment: Guys , sorry for the confusion but I forgot to mention one important thing, I realize I could use TEXT-ALIGN:CENTER. But this H1 has a border around it, so if  I leave it as a BLOCK it will show the border for the whole width of the page, but I thought by making it INLINE it would have a nice tight border around the H1, but then I cant center it using the MARGIN AUTO trick...just trying to understand WHY

Comment: Edit your answer rather then commenting.

Answer (score 5):

You can use padding to get a tight border, without setting the h1 as inline (which can't be centered using automatic margins).

```
h1 {
    padding: 0;
    width: 35;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    // border: ...
}
```

Comment: Emil thank you for answer, can you explain why an inline element cannot be centered using auto margins?

Answer (score 5):

A block level element has a line break before and after it so it has a definite beginning and end. It is rectangular in shape and can have a width defined.

An inline level element is contained within a block level element and can span multiple lines and does not have to define a rectangular region. According to section 10.3 of the [w3c Visual formatting model](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html) for inline elements: The 'width' property does not apply. A computed value of 'auto' for 'margin-left' or 'margin-right' becomes a used value of '0'.

You cannot center something that may begin in the middle of one line and end in the middle of another.

For example, how would you **center 
the text** that is bold and spans two lines?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried "text-align: center"?

Answer (score 1):

use "text-align:center "on DIV

Answer (score 1):

The first doesn't work because on inline elements, the **automatic margin is zero**.

margin: auto; *does* work on inline elements, it just doesn't have the same effect as on block-level elements.

(To demonstrate this: if you take an inline element, apply a specific margin to it, and then apply an automatic margin to it, its margin will be zero.)

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to put "text-align: center" on the H1. See [this documentation](http://www.w3schools.com/CSS/pr_text_text-align.asp).

Also, you can remove the margin-left and margin-right rules.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think your first solution works because you're setting it as inline and only block level elements can be given auto margins IIRC. Also, without setting an explicit width, the auto margin trick doesn't work too great.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
h1 {margin: 0pt auto; display: inline-block; min-width: 1%;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Considering you state your H1 needs a border that doesn't stretch to it's parent container, I recommend using a combination of styling on the DIV wrapper and the H1 element (paste this in to play w/ it):

```
<style type="text/css">
div.myHeadingClass {
    text-align: center;
    border: 1px solid #d7d7d7;
    padding: 15px;
}

div.myHeadingClass h1 {
    display: inline;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid red;
}
</style>

<div class="myHeadingClass">
<h1>My Big Ole Heading</h2>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Dude, it's simple. just like seb stated above.

Just set the H1 to padding 0, and instead of doing "margin-right:auto;margin-left:auto;" save the hassle and do "margin:auto" along with the set width. quick and easy.